# Closest Pair between 2 sets of powers

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, optimization

Assume $a$ and $b$ are natural numbers, $A=\{a,a^2,a^3,\cdots\}$ and $B=\{b,b^2,b^3,\cdots\}$, find $\min\left|a_i-b_j\right|$ where $a_i\in A$ and $b_j\in B$.

For example, if $a=3$, $b=10$, then $\min\left|a_i-b_j\right|=\left|3^2-10^1\right|=1$.

Variation: what if $a$ and $b$ are both prime numbers?

Comment: Take logs and change-of-base rule, perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Catalan's conjecture states that the only solutions to $a^n-b^m=1$ with $a,b,n,m>1$ is $3^2=2^3+1$. This was only proven in 2002 by Preda Mihăilescu using rather sophisticated algebraic methods. So I wouldn't expect an easy solution.

Comment: The given problem is likely out of reach, at least extremely difficult.